# Solving A System Of Equations

Tags: c++, geometry, trigonometry

I am currently writing a program which will calculate the Circumcenter of a triangle in a 2D space. The Circumcenter of triangle is the point where the three perpendicular bisectors of the sides of a triangle meet.

The steps to find the circumcenter of a triangle are as follows:
1)Calculate the midpoint of all sides
2)Fine the slope of all sides
3)Calculate the slope of the perpendicular bisectors
4)Substitute for the equation "y - y1 = m(x-x1)" for each side
5)Solve the systems of equations finding the x,y of the circumcenter

My program needs to find the circumcenter which is solved by solving the prior system of equations, I do not know how write this section of code and that is where I need help. How do I write a function or 2, which will take in all th required values and solve 2 of the equations?

```
Note:
In the circumcenter equation y - y1 = m(x-x1)
y1=Midpoint of that side(y component)
m=slope of the same side
x1=Midpoint of that side(x component)
Once the vakues are substituted in you simplify them, then you must solve for x,y.
```

My current code does everything else required, meaning I already have all the variables solved for up until the system of equations.
Sources
http://www.mathopenref.com/circumcenter.html

http://math.tutorcircle.com/geometry/how-to-find-the-circumcenter-of-a-triangle-algebraically.html

Comment: We don't do your homework. What did you try? Where are you stuck? What did you try so far to solve it?

Comment: I don't know how to begin at all with the actual system of equations, my program does every other step so far though(calculating midpoint, slope, perpendicular bisector) and stores them into variables, i didn't feel it was necessary to paste the code in, since the questions doesn't require it. I also read another Stackoverflow question which was similar, but their equations where in y=mx+b form, which isn't my case.

Comment: According to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: Can you solve the equations on paper? Then just code the resulting formulas. And if you can't solve a system of two equations on paper, then it is not a programming question.

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/soe/SE211105/SE211105.html

Comment: either use vectors and line/line intersection formula (no need to solve any system of equations for this you can solve it graphicaly) or go for gauss elimination method or determinant based inverse matrix computation ...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider this [cozy c++ library](https://github.com/ohhmm/openmind/blob/77d79f62ded371579ed2812850b81a9f30d2693e/omnn/math/test/Stasis.cpp#L20) for this purpose.

You can build total formula using variables and put it in [static](https://github.com/ohhmm/openmind/blob/77d79f62ded371579ed2812850b81a9f30d2693e/omnn/math/Sum.cpp#L1391) object.

Then just input may be  used to [evaluate](https://github.com/ohhmm/openmind/blob/77d79f62ded371579ed2812850b81a9f30d2693e/omnn/math/test/08_System.cpp#L250) into copied formula object.